# Ad Network with Manual Ad Approval and Whitelisting Options for Publishers

Tags: wordpress, ads, blogger, blogs, adsense

I'm new here and currently in search of an ad network or exchange that allows for the flexibility to **manually choose the ads displayed on my blog**. By this, I mean personally reviewing each ad before it goes live. I know it's not the typical way things are done, but I'm committed to finding a solution.

To provide a clearer picture, I'm looking for something akin to the Google Ad Review Center, but with a proactive feature. Unlike the Ad Review Center, where ads appear on your website before you review them, I need a solution that enables me to review ads before they actually show up on my blog.

If any of you have encountered or are using an ad network that accommodates such preferences, or at least has **a whitelist of advertisers**(not a blacklist or block categories like Adsense), I would greatly appreciate your insights. I'm willing to invest the time to personally curate ads that align perfectly with my beliefs.

I understand this may not be a common question, but any tips or suggestions would be invaluable to me. Feel free to share your experiences or recommendations.

Note: The only thing I found is buySellAds website that has a "Self-Serve Platform"